# How to access List element present inside a map in scala?

Tags: list, scala, dictionary

I'm trying to learn scala from last couple of days so please bear with me.

I'm bit confused accessing the list element in scala. If it is accessed directly from a list `apply` method works however if it is within a map then gives error.

Below is what I'm trying to do -

```
val m1 = List(1, 3, 5, 2)
val res = m1.apply(3)

//Output
m1: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 5, 2)
res: Int = 2
```

The same when done from within a map it throws error -

```
val m2 = Map(3 -> List(2, 3, 4, 5), 4 -> "for", 2 -> "cs")

print(m2(3).apply(2))

Error:An error was encountered:
<console>:27: error: value apply is not a member of java.io.Serializable
       print(m2(3).apply(2))
                   ^
```

I also tried `m2(3)(2)` as suggested in some of the threads but got `<console>:27: error: java.io.Serializable does not take parameters`

Please let me know where exactly it is going wrong. Coming from `python` background we can directly access it by `m2[3][2]`

Comment: BTW accessing `List` elements by an index is both inefficient and unidiomatic. My advice would be to pick a good book, course, or tutorial that actually teaches the language and its idioms, rather than just syntax.

Comment: Change `m2` to `val m2: Map[Int, Seq[_]] = Map(3 -> List(2, 3, 4, 5), 4 -> "for", 2 -> "cs")` would work. (But it may does not work as your expected.)

Comment: In Scala one would not normally put values of completely unrelated types in a `Map`. If you're used to programming that way, you may have some un-learning and re-learning to do when working in a statically typed language such as Scala.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Scala is a statically typed programming language](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/type-declaration#introduction). This means that the compiler determines the type of a variable at compile time. Compiler will infer type of `Map` based on passed elements and for the `m2` type would be `Map[Int, Serializable]` (I assume you are using Scala 2 compiler) where `Serializable` does not have `apply` method with parameters. Quick and dirty approach would be casting via `asInstanceOf`:

```scala
m2(3).asInstanceOf[List[Int]].apply(3)
```

But in general it is highly discouraged approach. You should consider modeling your domain using type-safe techniques.

Comment: Got it. But do you think of any other approach other than this? As you mentioned `asInstanceOf` is a dirty approach

Comment: @djm it depends on the task, you can use heterogenous maps (i.e. map storing values of the same type) and it will work out of the box, you can create a case class which will contained typed data. Currently it is hard to tell what actually do you want to achieve.

Comment: In Scala 3 union types could work. In Scala 2 one would have to wrap in `Either` or some manually written ADT.

Comment: @GuruStron it is just for learning no use case as such. That's why I asked what will you suggest.

Answer (score 3):

We do not usually put different unrelated types inside a collection or a map. This is not a common practice in Scala and typed languages.

First, the error you had is not specifically related to Maps.

Let's look at this example:

```scala
val m1: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 5, 2)
val x: Int = m1(1) // the same as m2.apply(3)
val y: Int = x + 1
```

the list has integer elements and as such its type `Seq[Int]`. That is a List of Int elements. We can retrieve an element of the list, which is an Int, and we can `+` another integer.

Now, let's look at a different example

```scala
val m2: List[Any] = List(1, 3 , "cat", m1)
val x2: Any = m2(3) 
val y2 = x2 + 1// This will not compile
```

When we add elements of different types in the same list, the type of the list is the intersection of those types. In this case that intersection is `Any`. This gives us a `List[Any]`. When we try to retrieve an element from the list, we get `Any`. Since the compiler doesn't recognize that as something it can `+ 1` to. It will result in an error.

This is what happened in the map example.

```scala
val m2: Map[Int, Serializable] = Map(3 -> List(2, 3, 4, 5), 4 -> "for", 2 -> "cs")
```

The intersection of the values in the map is `Serializable` and when you retrieve an element from the map. Scala cannot tell it is a list, and as such it will not allow retrieving something from it.

Now, that said, in practice, a list could still have elements of different (usually related types). This takes us to a topic that you will probably see in the future while learning Scala, pattern matching. This is how that looks like:

```scala
m2(3) match {
  case l: List[Int] => l(2) // same as l.apply(2)
  case s: String => println(s)
}
```

While this is better than casting, we usually use collections in a more fluid way. to do multiple transformation. It is very rare to get an element from a list by index. The following is a more advanced example, but to give an idea.

```scala
  val m3: Map[Int, Any] = m2 // still map of int to any
    .map {
      case (key, value: List[Int]) => (key, value(2) * 2) // if it is a list multiply the second element of the list by 2
      case (key, value: String) => (key, value.toUpperCase) // if it is a string convert the string to upper case
      case (key, value) => (key, value) // otherwise pass it as is
    }
    .filter {
      case (key, value: Int) => value > 10 // if it is an int keep it if it is greater than 10
      case (key, value) => true // otherwise keep it
    }
  
  m3.foreach(element => println(element)) // prints everything in the map
```

Overall, Scala is a beautiful and expressive language. There is a bit of a learning curve but it is really rewarding.